# Can I call a stored procedure on each iteration of an array? PHP

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, sql-update, associative-array

I want to loop through an associative array that represents a table's columns and values, and call a stored procedure on each iteration that will insert each value into its respective column. The assoc. array and loop looks like this:

```
    public static function update(
        int $auctionId,
        string $title,
        string $description
        ) : void
    {
        $new = [
            'auction_title' => $title,
            'description' => $description
        ];

        foreach ($new as $columnName => $value) {
            Database::conn()->callSP('sp_auctions_update', [$auctionId, $columnName, $value]);
        }
    }
```

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sp_auctions_update $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_auctions_update(
    IN auctionId INT UNSIGNED,
    IN columnName,
    IN value,
    )

    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

    UPDATE auctions SET @columnName=@value, WHERE id=@auctionId;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Is this possible to do? Or is there a better alternative? Many thanks

Comment: Do not use user-defined variables names (which starts from `@`) for local variables and procedure/function parameters - this may cause unpleasant effects.

Comment: The procedure is errorneous. You cannot use a parameter as column name in a query (I mean `@columnName`) - you need dynamic SQL (prepared statement) for this purposes.

Comment: Thank you, do you know what the prepared statement would look like in this instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do you know what the prepared statement would look like in this instance?

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_auctions_update(
    IN auctionId INT UNSIGNED,
    IN columnName VARCHAR(64),
    IN `value` INT UNSIGNED
    )

    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

-- Build SQL query text, insert column name from variable into it
    SET @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE auctions SET ', columnName, '=? WHERE id=?;');
-- Reassign parameters values from local variables to user-defined ones
-- because local variables cannot be used in USING
    SET @value := `value`;
    SET @auctionId := auctionId;
-- Prepare and execute the query
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt USING @value, @auctionId;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

Alternatively you may concat ALL parameters values into the query text:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_auctions_update(
    IN auctionId INT UNSIGNED,
    IN columnName VARCHAR(64),
    IN `value` INT UNSIGNED
    )

    SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    MODIFIES SQL DATA

BEGIN

-- Build SQL query text, insert parameters from variables into it
    SET @sql := CONCAT('UPDATE auctions SET ', columnName, '=\'', `value`, '\' WHERE id=', auctionId, ';');
-- Prepare and execute the query
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

END
```

---

Caution.

The `columnName` parameter value is inserted into SQL query text as-is - so injection is possible. You must add the code which controls this parameter value. For example you may check that the column with provided name exists in table structure.

Another 2 parameters cannot be a source of injection due to their numeric datatype.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, I'm new to MySql so learning a lot. One last question - what happens if the `value` variable (IN `value` INT UNSIGNED) could be assigned values that have different data types? Ie the first iteration might be a number, but second a string?

Comment: @Aejg If the value has string type, but it may be converted to numeric correctly then the procedure will be executed successfully. Otherwise the error is raised (which can be supressed by clearing strict server's SQL mode). See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=58af359b13907b4e2699c91c397321af).

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately for my situation there are strings such as "bike" or "car" that I'm looping over that aren't meant to be converted to INT.

Comment: @Aejg If so declare this parameter as, for example, TEXT - and it will accept everything.